# ExcelJS not importing xlsx data

Tags: exceljs

1. I'm NOT using the node load option
2. External js files ARE being called and loaded
3. The xlsx file to be imported IS local to the published files
4. This is the script so far - all I want to do is check to see if the source is being imported and populating the created workbook

*var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

var importBook = "./story_content/external_files/sample.xlsx";

console.dir( importBook );

workbook.xlsx.readFile( importBook );

console.dir ( workbook );

var ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

console.dir( ws );*

[image]

line 112 is the result of console.dir ( workbook ); which says to me that NOTHING is either loaded OR imported, and I can't understand why not....wasted too much time trying possible solutions so i'm reaching out to the community.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 0):

- You can try this.

```js
    const filePath: string = `assets/1962.xlsx`;

    const buffer = await fetch(filePath).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
    const workbook = new Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.load(buffer);

    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    console.dir(worksheet);
```